# Ubuntu 18.04.4 live usb won't boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, uefi, live-usb, secure-boot

```
PC: Dell Inspiron 15 7000 gamin
Proc: Intel i7 4-core
GPU: Nvidia gtx 1060ti
Uefi Mode: ON
Secure Boot: ON
Current OS: Windows 10 Home
```

My live usb won't boot after choosing any options like try without installing or just install ubuntu. I tried setting nomodeset in options and found out that the error is efi stub: Uefi Secure boot on. I don't wont to switch off secure boot, I never had such an issue with installing ubuntu, what's the matter and why can't I install it. I want to have dual boot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: You will need to disable Secure Boot to be able to install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: I read the answer, so I'll have to install it in legacy mode, and the install grub-efi, configure boot and then if everything goes fine, I will be able to boot to ubuntu in uefi mode? Am i right?

Comment: No. Leave it in UEFI mode. Disable Secure Boot. Install Ubuntu.

Comment: You can leve Secure Boot on, boot with `nomodeset`, install Ubuntu, then you'll have to disable SB before instaooing Nvidia proprietary driver.

Comment: @Pilot6 Still has to disable SB. Might as well do it now, and then proceed with a normal Ubuntu install.

Comment: @heynnema Ubuntu installs with SB with no problems, the problem is the driver. It doesn't matter when disable SB.

Comment: @Pilot6 Of course. The difference is having to boot with nomodeset, and then manually installing Nvidia drivers. Why go through all that? Just disable SB now, and proceed all the way through the Ubuntu install... much easier for new users.

Comment: None of the option worked, anyway I'll try installing new ubuntu 20.04 when it leaves beta testing. thx to all

Comment: I am trying to install ubuntu with SB off now, and nomodeset, will status update, for u to help.

Comment: Usually with sb on i get error message efi;stub UEFI SB ON

Comment: My pc now restarts after hitting ubuntu option

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution. I started ubuntu live usb in secure boot off, and did this

```
sudo mokutil --reset
```

After I've rebooted with secure boot on, and did reset the mok with provided password.
Afterwards I started ubuntu live usb in secure boot off again, and ran this command

```
sudo mokutil --enroll-key
```

Then after that I enrolled key with secure boot on, and after that Ubuntu Live usb could boot in uefi secure boot on.
Hope it helps the others.